# Font size issue after updating to Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio

This morning I updated to Android Studio 1.4 and the font size of my editor is much bigger that before. I Use the Darcula scheme. When I check the configuration for the Darcula scheme, it is using Monospaced font with 12 size.

Anyone else with the same issue, or is it just me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue just by creating a copy of the scheme (by clicking on Save As...)

With the new scheme (with same configuration as before, just the scheme is different) the issue is resolved.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue is still present in the terminal view.

Comment: Go to the section "Console Fonts" and do the same as above

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I have this issue too and don't know how to fix it - OS X El Capitan

Comment: @azurh Go to Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Font and at the top next to the current scheme click on 'Save As'. That will make a copy of your current scheme which you should use and should fix the font problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when I updated to **Android Studio 1.4**. My font was broken. I thought it's because of my OS upgrade(**OS X El Capitan**). After trying lots of different stuffs I found that it's the problem with JDK.

You may be using higher version(>1.6) of JDK now. **You just need to install JDK 1.6 which is the default for font rendering in Android Studio**.
If you're using OS X,
then download JDK 1.6 from [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US) abd install it.
To check which version of java you are using run this command.

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines && ls -l
```

After installing JDK 1.6. Restart Android Studio. You'll see your beautiful anti-aliased font back there.
Cheers.

Comment: This fix restored the font rendering to its appearance before the OS upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

If you have issues with the terminal font try this. Ctr + shift + A followed by [increase/decrease font size]